# gc.get_referrers returns a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, garbage-collection

As far as I understood, `gc.get_referrers(my_obj)` should return a list of the objects that refer to `my_obj`.
However, I'm currently seeing this behaviour:

```py
import sys
import gc

my_obj = []
ref_1 = my_obj
ref_2 = my_obj
sys.getrefcount(my_obj)  # Returns 4, as expected

gc.get_referrers(my_obj)
```

This last command returns the following:

```py
[
    {
        '__name__': '__main__', 
        '__doc__': None, 
        '__package__': None, 
        '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, 
        '__spec__': None, 
        '__annotations__': {}, 
        '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 
        'sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>, 
        'gc': <module 'gc' (built-in)>, 
        'my_obj': [], 
        'ref_1': [], 
        'ref_2': []
    }
]
```

I was expecting to receive a list of 4 objects, but `gc.get_referrers(my_obj)` is returning a list that contains only one dictionary instead.

What does this dictionary represent? Where is it documented? And why is `gc.get_referrers(my_obj)` returning it instead of the 4 objects I was expecting?

Comment: It's returning the `globals()` dictionary, which contains the association between variable names and their values.

Comment: What 4 objects were you expecting it to return? Variables aren't objects.

Comment: BTW, there are only 3 permanent references to the object. The 4th that `getrefcount()` counted included its own argument list, which went away when the function returned.

Comment: Those references are the last 3 items in the dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. If I use lists as in `ref_1 = [my_obj]` I get the output I would expect (since they're now objects). But are `sys.getrefcount` and `gc.get_referrers` counting the same elements? For example, it seems like `gc.getrefcount` counts the association in `globals()`, while `sys.getrefcount` doesn't. Is this correct?

Comment: When you do `ref_1 = [my_obj]` there are now 2 references: 1 in the `globals()` dictionary for `my_obj`, `1` in the list `[my_obj]`. When you call `sys.getrefcount()` there will temporarily be a 3rd reference in the argument list.

Comment: Why isn't this temporary reference also created with `gc.get_referrers(my_obj)`, since we're passing it as an argument here as well?

Comment: It is. As I said earlier, that's why the count was 4, not 3.

Comment: Sorry, I meant with `gc.get_referrers(my_obj)`. I edited the message.

Comment: Argument lists aren't Python objects, so `get_referrers()` can't include them.

Comment: Also, local variables aren't objects. If you do `x = []; print(gc.get_referrers(x))` inside a function, it will return an empty list. But if you do `y = locals()` inside the function, the local variables are turned into a dictionary, then that dictionary is returned.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that `sys.getrefcount` would return the number of references to an object, while `gc.get_referrers` would return _exactly_ those references. As you hinted, it looks like they actually refer to different things though: `sys.getrefcount` returns all references (including arguments), while `gc.get_referrers` only returns the objects that refer to the given object.

Comment: Right. There are lots of internal references that don't come from python objects. they're in the refcount, but not referrers.

Comment: @Barmar if you could summarize our conversation in an answer I’ll be happy to accept it. I think it would be more readable for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects can be referenced by other Python objects, but there are also lots of internal references from the interpreter itself.

Internal references include local variables, temporary results in expressions, and and function-call argument lists.

`sys.getrefcount()` simply retrieves the reference count field of the object, so it will count all these internal references. It will likely be 1 more than the number of permanent references, because the object itself is in the argument list of the call to `sys.getrefcount()`, so its reference count is incremented during the call.

Global variables are not first-class objects in Python (contrast with Lisp, where global variables are implemented using *symbol* objects, which have a value cell containing the value). They're implemented as items in the `globals()` dictionary. So in your code snippet, when you created several global variables referencing the list, `gc.get_referrers()` simply returned that dictionary.

`gc.get_referrers()` can only return Python objects, so its result will not include internal references. I suppose they could have devised some way to represent these as some kind of proxy object (it might print as something like `<arglist #12345>`), but since these are often transient it wasn't felt necessary (consider that the argument to `gc.get_referrers()` would no longer exist when you're examining the return value).

Local variables are implemented using internal references (the reference comes from the stack frame containing local state), so they normally don't show up in `gc.get_referrers()` results.
However, if you call `locals()`, this forces a dictionary to be created containing all the local variables. Since this is a normal object, it will be returned after that point, similar to the way you got the `globals()` dictionary in your top-level code. `sys.getrefcount()` will count both the internal reference and the reference from this dictionary.